# Taking a pointer passed to a function, then putting it into another function

Tags: c++

I'm writing a password generator that can read and write to a file. I have a function that takes an empty string, then modifies it. The function would look something like this:

```
void password_create(string *passwd)
```

Inside that function, I call a write function that writes out to a file with the password, it would look something like this:

```
void write_out(string file_name, string *passwd)
```

Then the total code looks like this:

```
void password_create(string *passwd) {
    *passwd = "something";
    write_out(&passwd);
}
```

The compile complains that I can't convert `std::basic_string<char>**` to `std::basic_string<char>*`.

I'm relatively new to C++, and this program is just to help me get acquainted with the language. I can pass `passwd` into the `write_out()` function without a `*` or `&` to denote a pointer or reference just fine. It won't give me an error if I type:

```
*passwd = "something";
write_out(passwd);
```

It doesn't affect the overall completion of the program, I was just curious as to why I get that error.

Comment: TL;DR; Why are you taking a pointer to `std::string`? Rather pass by reference or by value.

Comment: If the function takes an empty string, why does it take a string at all?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] that demonstrates your problem. Those arbitrary code snippets aren't helpful to answer your question concisely.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `passwd` is already a pointer to a `std::string`, therefore taking the address of it via `&passwd` will give you something of type `std::string**` - so if `write_out` expects a parameter of type `std::string*` but receives the `std::string**` then the compiler will give you an error as you saw.  So don't use `&` when passing `passwd` to `write_out()`:

```
write_out(passwd);
```

But all that aside, you should just pass the `std::string` variables by reference rather than by pointer, as mentioned in the comments and the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use pointers, in c++ prefer using pass by reference:

```
void password_create(std::string &passwd) {
    passwrd = "something";
    ...
```

Then ensure that you create the string as you intend:

```
std::string myString;
password_create(myString);
```

That way you will have the memory you expect and you dont need to worry about pointer semantics.

Answer (score 0):

No need to overcomplicate things. I dont see where pointers are needed in this case at all. Just make a function to generate a password and return it.

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

string password_create() {
    return "generated password";
}

void write_password_to_file(string file, string password) {
    ofstream stream(file);
    stream << password;
    stream.close();
}

int main() {
    auto password = password_create();
    write_password_to_file("pathtofile.txt", password);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answers you should actually take the `std::string` parameter by reference instead of a pointer.

---

Well assuming that the `write_out()` has some signature like

```
write_out(char* passwd);
```

or

```
write_out(const char* passwd);
```

you can pass [`std::string::operator[]()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at):

```
void password_create(string *passwd) {
    *passwd = "something";
    write_out(&(*passwd)[0]);
}
```

Comment: @NathanOliver Fixed.

Comment: You should use [`std::string::c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) instead of `std::string::operator[]`, eg: `write_out(passwd.c_str());`